# React-Native with Redux: API objects appear in my console.log but not my view

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, redux, react-redux

I’m building a Simple Sports App using `react`, `react-native`, `react-native-router-flux`, `react-redux`, with `redux` and trying to pull an `api` of top news object to my `view`. The object that I need displays on my `console log` but cant get it to show up on my `view`.

The error that I am getting is:

> Cannot read property 'cloneWithRowsAndSections' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneWithRowsAndSections' of
>   undefined
>       at NewsList.componentWillMount

Is there something that I am missing?

NewsList:

```
export default class NewsList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 != row2,
        sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
       });
      this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(props.ListData)
      }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    const dataSource = this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(nextProps.ListData);
    this.setState({dataSource});
  }


  componentWillMount(){
    // console.log("whats This: ",this.props.ListData);
    let data = this.props.ListData;
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(data)
    });
  }
```

News_View:

```
render(){
console.log('TopNews', this.state.TopNews);
if(this.state.TopNews.length == 0){
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={styles.LiveStyle}>
        <Live style={styles.LiveStyle} />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={[styles.NotFollowTeamMsg, styles.centerTeamMsg]}>
          Your not connected to the api
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
} else {
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <NewsList
          ListData={this.state.TopNews}


        />
      </View>
  )
}


 }
```

In the constructor, I tried changing `const ds = ...`, as `this.ds = ...` but that only lead to the error:

> ds is not defined 
>   ReferenceError: ds is not defined

I tried taking out the constructor function:

```
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 != row2,
sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
});
```

then locate it outside of NewsList class, and I `setState`,like this:

```
this.setState({
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(data)
});
```

but that only lead to the error:

> Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'bind' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

2 Options:

1.In your constructor make the `const ds = ...`, as `this.ds = ...`

2.Take this out of the `constructor` function:

```
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 != row2,
sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
});
```

and locate it outside of `NewsList` class.

Now, when you `setState`, do it like this:

```
this.setState({
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(data)
});
```

Comment: I have already tried both of those options @gran33. The error that comes out is: $ds is not defined
ReferenceError: ds is not defined $

Comment: @Checkk I got your error also, and my suggestion worked for me. Your class doesn't know your `ds` variable, since u didn't add it to `this.ds = ...`